# PySpark equivalent to pandas .isin()

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark DataFrame

```
data = [
    ('foo'), 
    ('baz'), 
    ('bar'), 
    ('qux')
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ( "group"))
```

Now I want to create a new column `number` that is `0` if `group` is in the list `zeros = ['baz', 'qux']`, `1` if it is in `ones = ['foo']` and `2` otherwise. In pandas I'd use `.isin()` but I don't understand how to solve that in PySpark.

Here is what I've tried but it does not work

```
df.withColumn("number", 
                func.when(func.col("group")  == array(*[lit(x) for x in ones])), 1)
               .otherwise(2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `isin` in Pyspark. See the syntax below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

zeros = ['baz', 'qux']
ones = ['foo']

df2 = df.withColumn('number',
    F.when(F.col('group').isin(zeros), 0)
     .when(F.col('group').isin(ones), 1)
     .otherwise(2)
)

df2.show()
+-----+------+
|group|number|
+-----+------+
|  foo|     1|
|  baz|     0|
|  bar|     2|
|  qux|     0|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. What I did wrong was using F.when for the second when clause. I thought the `isin()` was the problem